# Keep the inline behavior of the container but set it's height to needed value

Tags: css

I got a container (`div` in example) with sub-containers (`span`) inside. Container and subcontainers should have the same height, but different background colors. Subcontainers should wrap like simple words, but the background should wrap with them.

So if I set main container's `display` to `inline-block`, it becomes a rectangle, but other stuff works good.

When i set the `display` property to `inline`, its height could not be adjusted in CSS anymore.

So I've made an example, as you could see, it works ALMOST well, except main container's height (it's smaller than subcontainers')

How can i keep the inline behavior of the container but set it's height to needed value?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<style>
body {
 width: 300px;
}

div {
 background: #000;
 color: #fff;
 display: inline;
 height: 25px;
 line-height: 25px;
 padding: 0 10px;
}

div span {
 display: inline-block;

 height: 25px;
 line-height: 25px;
 background: #555;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>

<div>
 <span>some phrase</span>
 <span>some phrase</span>
 <span>some phrase</span>
 <span>some phrase</span>
 <span>some phrase</span>
 <span>some phrase</span>
 <span>some phrase</span>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems close:

```css
div {
  font-size: 25px; /* same as line-height */
}
div > span {
  vertical-align: top; /* fix alignment */
  font-size: 16px; /* reset to default */
}
```

```css
body {
  width: 300px;
}
div {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline;
  line-height: 25px;
  font-size: 25px;
}
div > span {
  vertical-align: top; /* fix alignment */
  display: inline-block;
  height: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
  background: #555;
  font-size: 16px; /* reset to default */
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>some phrase</span>
  <span>some phrase</span>
  <span>some phrase</span>
  <span>some phrase</span>
  <span>some phrase</span>
  <span>some phrase</span>
  <span>some phrase</span>
</div>
```

If you have vertical padding, include that in `line-height` and `font-size`:

```css
body {
  width: 300px;
}
div {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline;
  line-height: 40px; /* 10 + 25 + 5 */
  font-size: 40px; /* 10 + 25 + 5 */
}
div > span {
  vertical-align: top; /* fix alignment */
  display: inline-block;
  height: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
  background: #555;
  font-size: 16px; /* reset to default */
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>some phrase</span>
  <span>some phrase</span>
  <span>some phrase</span>
  <span>some phrase</span>
  <span>some phrase</span>
  <span>some phrase</span>
  <span>some phrase</span>
</div>
```

Comment: nice. and if i have top/bottom padding?